# Changing subject and verb positions in statements and questions

Tags: grammar, word-order, questions, subject-verb-inversion

We always change subject and verb positions in whenever we want to ask a question such as "What is your name?". But when it comes to statements like the following, which form is correct?

> 1. I don't understand what **are you** talking about.
> 2. I don't understand what **you are** talking about.

Another example

> 1. Do you know what time **is it**?
> 2. Do you know what time **it is**?

Another example

> 1. Do you care how **do I feel** about this?
> 2. Do you care how **I feel** about this?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/608581/2085).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all the cases you reported, the second sentence is the correct one. It is similar to the word order in *They asked who I was*.

Answer (score 11):

The general answer is that you only move the verb ahead of the subject within a main clause.  All of your examples have [WH-movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement) within an embedded clause.

> 1. What **have you** been doing today? *(main clause)*
> 2. I asked [what **you have** been doing today]. *(embedded clause)*
> 3. I am annoyed because of [what **you have** been doing today]. *(embedded clause)*
> 4. Can you tell me [what **you have** been doing today]? *(embedded clause)*
> 5. [What **you have** been doing today] annoys me. *(embedded clause)*

To know whether you are dealing with the main clause or an embedded clause, you have to think about what is the main verb of the whole sentence.

Answer (score 5):

Number 2 is correct in each case.

The reason for this is that "what" and "how" are being used as [relative pronouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_pronoun). If the clause which follows it has a subject, it comes before the verb.

Compare that to a question, where the verb comes first, e.g.:

> What **are you** talking about?

versus:

> I don't understand what **you are** talking about.