# ''I don't know what" + direct object

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, word-order, subject-verb-inversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing subject and verb positions in statements and questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/changing-subject-and-verb-positions-in-statements-and-questions)
>   [Why do we put the verb to be at the end of these questions?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61714/why-do-we-put-the-verb-to-be-at-the-end-of-these-questions)

Is the expression

> I don't know what is an amplifier.

incorrect?

If so, is the correct version

> I don't know what an amplifier is.

and why is the first variant wrong?

Answer (score 2):

A question-word (like *what*) not immediately followed by a verb forms a noun phrase. "What an amplifier is" is a noun phrase meaning the property which makes an amplifier into an amplifier rather than anything else. A noun phrase can form the object of a sentence.

A question-word (like *what*) immediately followed by a verb forms a question. "What is an amplifier" is a question. A question cannot be a noun phrase which forms the object of a sentence.

"I don't know what an amplifier is" has a subject (*I*), a negated main verb (*don't know*) and an object (*what an amplifier is*).

"I don't know what is an amplifier" has a subject, a negated main verb, and then a question. In response to a question like "Can you describe an amplifier?" you **could** say "I don't know: what's an amplifier?" responding to the first question and asking one of your own.

***Which*** behaves slightly differently. "I don't know which is an amplifier" is perfectly grammatical because it's actually an ellipsis — the object of the sentence has been omitted: "I don't know which *[piece of equipment]* is an amplifier".

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct in different circumstances, with different meanings.

I don't know what an amplifier is. (Perhaps I missed the physics lesson on amplifiers, or have never been to a shop selling hi-fi equipment.)

I don't know what is an amplifier. (There are so many pieces of electronic equipment in this room - any or none of them might be an amplifier.)