# Are these sentences both structured correctly?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

> I know what **is** the meaning of this.
>
> I know what the meaning of this **is**.

If the first sentence is considered correct, can someone please explain the reasoning?

Edit:

The answer of the "Changing Subject and Verb" post illustrates my question, not the answer. Another example:

> To know whether you are dealing with the main clause or an embedded clause, you have to think about what **is** the main verb of the whole sentence.

Compared to:

> To know whether you are dealing with the main clause or an embedded clause, you have to think about what the main verb of the whole sentence **is**.

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times before, e.g. [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/changing-subject-and-verb-positions-in-statements-and-questions), [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61714/) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93607/i-dont-know-what-direct-object). I don't understand how you can say that the answers there don't satisfy you after accepting *the exact same answer* here. In fact the answer here is much less detailed than the ones on the older questions.

Comment: I think I explained why quite clearly above; the best voted answer of the link you provided included a nice explanation, but the first sentence following the explanation included a sentence that completely contradicted the rule that was just explained. Because of this, I thought I must not be understanding it correctly. The other links were very helpful, though. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is wrong: this is an **indirect/subordinate/dependent question**, which has **regular word order** (subject-verb), not the inverted order of an independent question with a question mark.