# "A question in a question"

Tags: word-order, questions

I've got two questions for you.

Number one: I've always been confused about what I call "a question in a question" (maybe there is a technical term for that but I don't know it). What I mean is... which one of these two sentences is correct?

1) Can I ask you where **are you** from?

or

2) Can I ask you where **you are** from?

Then I have a second question which is quite similar to the first one: should I say

a) I would like to ask you where **you are** from

or

b) I would like to ask you where **are you** from

Thanks for your help.

Comment: None of those four alternatives will elicit any useful information. The answer to *1* and *2* is either "Yes" or "No" and *a* and *b* are not questions. Just **ask the question.**

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean.. I just gave 4 examples because I thought it would help people better understand my question. Basically what I would like to know is: when I have a question which is actually made up of two questions, am I supposed to put both of them in the interrogative form or should the second one be in the affirmative word order? That's the question behind 1) and 2)...

Comment: See [Changing subject and verb positions in statements and questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/changing-subject-and-verb-positions-in-statements-and-questions): "only move the verb ahead of the subject within a main clause."