# Why does the ordering of the following sentences matter?

Tags: grammar

Recently I was been posted with this question: Why is 
1. I don't know who is he. (grammatically incorrect)
2. I don't know who he is. (grammatically correct)
Even as a native English speaker, I could not give the person asking this question a definite answer or explanation. Please enlighten me on this. Thanks!

Comment: I can only imagine the first sentence being used with a comma in between: "I don't know, who is he?" is something that a person might say out loud, as speech does not adhere to formal grammar.

Comment: Another related question, [Changing subject and verb positions in statements and questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/changing-subject-and-verb-positions-in-statements-and-questions).

Comment: Careless me, didn't realise this question is about indirect speech. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Who is he" can only be a complete sentence, whereas "who he is" can only be a clause embedded in another sentence. In English where there is little conjugation, word order is more heavily relied upon to make that kind of distinction, so this shows up a lot.

Comment: This sounds logical to me, I shall convey as such to my friend who posted me with this question. Thank you so much!