# Using Interrogative Words

Tags: grammar, questions, indirect-question

Which of these two is correct?

1. Do you know what does this word mean?
2. Do you know what this word means?

And, which of these two is correct?

1. This does not explain where does it come from.
2. This does not explain where it comes from.

And, as far as possible, why.
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing subject and verb positions in statements and questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/changing-subject-and-verb-positions-in-statements-and-questions)